# Non-standard atlas for complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

Does the complex plane has more than one complex structure? Ofcourse one atlas is given by the identity map. Are there any other that is not analytically compatible with this standard one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $J$ denote the standard complex structure, and let $\varphi:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a non-holomorphic diffeomorphism. Then $\varphi^*J$ is a different complex structure on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: So something as simple as $ z \to \bar{z} $ would work (for $ \phi $ ) ?

Comment: @ardhajya Yes, it would.